# how to debug gulp-sourcemaps not doing anything?

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-sourcemaps, gulp-uglify

I have a fairly standard use case for `gulp-sourcemaps`

https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps

```
  gulp.src( bundle.src)
           .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
           .pipe(concat(bundle.dst + '.' + opts.ext))
            .pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/built'));
```

This produces appropriately concatenated and uglyified files. However there are no source map additions to them. `bundle.src` is an array of file paths. Not sure how to debug this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into [gulp-util](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-util). It may give you some insight into what is actually happening.

```
var gutil = require('gulp-util')
...
.pipe(sourcemaps.init().on('error', gutil.log))
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to specify where to write, like so:

```
.pipe(sourcemaps.write('./').on('error', gutil.log))
```

This didn't work: (no `.map` files generated)

```
.pipe(sourcemaps.write().on('error', gutil.log)
```