# problems with gulp traceur sourcemaps and uglify

Tags: node.js, gulp, uglifyjs

I have the following gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var traceur = require('gulp-traceur');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglifyjs');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/*.js')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(traceur())
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

When running this code i don't get a source map in the all.js file.

When i remove the line:

```
  .pipe(uglify())
```

I get the source map but then my code is not uglified.

I tried to debug the code with gulp-utils but did not find anything out([how to debug gulp-sourcemaps not doing anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26110830/how-to-debug-gulp-sourcemaps-not-doing-anything)).

How can this issue be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed 'gulp-uglifyjs' to 'gulp-uglify' and everything worked

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var traceur = require('gulp-traceur');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var gutil = require('gulp-util')

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/*.js')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init().on('error', gutil.log))
        .pipe(traceur())
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```